# How to Auto resize in XCodes 4.3.2

Tags: interface-builder, xcode4.3

After i upgraded into XCodes 4.3.2 , that's giving me headache.
In older version, We can auto resize our control with click on arrow like following photo

[image]

But in XCodes 4.3.2 that view was changed like

[image]

So what is scales and how it's work?
I really don't understand apple ever change also user interface when they release XCodes new Version.
Please explain how to work with it?

If my question is too easy for you, please forgive me asking like this question.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have "Use Auto Layout" checked in the *File Inspector* (the left hand tab of views you show)?  If so, uncheck it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer for my question.

That's need to disable auto resize function.

To disable deselect the "use auto layout" option in the Interface Builder design canvas.

After that, everything ok.